# When using addHeader in glide the same image appears always

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-glide

**Glide Version**: 3.7.0
**Integration libraries**: No
**Device/Android Version**: Fails on Nexus 4

Hello, I am trying to load some images from a dropbox folder. This needs authentification so I use the next code with the Dropbox rest ws:

```
GlideUrl glideUrl = new GlideUrl("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download", new LazyHeaders.Builder().addHeader("Authorization", auth).addHeader("Dropbox-API-Arg", "{\"path\": \"" + url + "\"}").build());
```

I have a FragmentPagerAdapter that has an image in each page, that is a Fragment. The problem is when I use a the above code I have always the same image in each page, but each page should have its own image. Also, I tried with Picasso and it worked fine (but much slower). But if I use the below code for an image of my public dropbox folder without using the authorization header everything works fine, I mean each page has its own image:

```
glideUrl = new GlideUrl(publicUrl);
```

Also the code with the Authorization is used in a recyclerView with a GridLayoutManager and it works perfectly, so I really don't know what is the problem. Could you help me, please?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution coming from the Glide repo:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1206

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue,this may help you
Glide-4.0.0-RC1

```
    Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    long offset = rightNow.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) +
                rightNow.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);

    long sinceMidnight = (rightNow.getTimeInMillis() + offset) %
                (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    Key signature = new MediaStoreSignature(response.body().getResponse()
   [0].getPhoto_Ext(), sinceMidnight, 0);


    Glide.with(this)
             .load(response.body().getResponse()[0].getPhotoExt())
             .clone().apply(signatureOf(signature))
             .into(profile_pic);
```

This may help some one with same problem.